# Why is this js code so slow?

Tags: javascript

This code takes 3 seconds on Chrome and 6s on Firefox.
If I write the code in Java and run it under Java 7.0 it takes only 10ms.
Chrome's JS engine is usually very fast. Why is it so slow here?
btw. this code is just for testing. I know it's not very practical way to write a fibonacci function

```
fib = function(n) {
  if (n < 2) {
    return n;
  } else {
    return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
  }
};

console.log(fib(32));
```

Comment: Interesting.... Several seconds in my Chrome browser, but instant in node.js.  Possible trick in Chrome using memoization: http://www.unlimitednovelty.com/2011/10/nodejs-has-jumped-shark.html

Comment: weird, I get 136ms in jsfiddle with chrome http://jsfiddle.net/TgNDJ/

Comment: jsPerf test case: http://jsperf.com/fib-test With Chrome 20, I get five ops or so a second average.

Comment: You really should provide the testing steps you took including what gave you the run times you've given.

Comment: At a guess, because javascript engines aren't optimised for recursion (doh!). The function makes a very large number of recursive calls, all of which must be stored waiting for the next to be finished. Note also that ECMAScript is single threaded, there is no mechanism for memory management or optimisation other than through efficient programming, and recursion isn't efficient. Try re-writing it as a loop.

Comment: @hobberwickey +1 for the fiddle with the clock time.  I also got a few ms when run with the fiddle.  When I copied the code into the Chrome console itself, and ran this within the console, it took over 9 _seconds_.

Comment: I found the problem. It only runs slow if you paste the code into the console. If you put it into a .js file and add it to a website it runs much faster(around 30 to 40 ms). I guess code that's pasted into the console is being interpreted and not jit compiled.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This isn't fault of javascript, but your algorithm. You're recomputing same subproblems over and over again, and it gets worse when N is bigger. This is call graph for a single call:

```
                  F(32)
               /         \
            F(31)            F(30)
          /     \           /      \
      F(30)     F(29)     F(29)    F(28)
    /  \      /     \     /   \     |    \
F(29) F(28) F(28) F(27) F(28) F(27) F(27) F(26)

... deeper and deeper
```

As you can see from this tree, you're computing some fibonacci numbers several times, for example F(28) is computed 4 times. From the "Algorithm Design Manual" book:

> How much time does this algorithm take to compute F(n)? Since F(n+1)
>   /F(n) ≈ φ = (1 + sqrt(5))/2 ≈ 1.61803, this means that F(n) > 1.6^n . Since our
>   recursion tree has only 0 and 1 as leaves, summing up to such a large
>   number means we must have at least 1.6^n leaves or procedure calls!
>   This humble little program takes **exponential time** to run!

You have to use memoization or build solution bottom up (i.e. small subproblems first).

This solution uses memoization (thus, we're computing each Fibonacci number only once):

```
var cache = {};
function fib(n) {
  if (!cache[n]) {
    cache[n] = (n < 2) ? n : fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
  }
  return cache[n];
}
```

This one solves it bottom up:

```
function fib(n) {
  if (n < 2) return n;
  var a = 0, b = 1;
  while (--n) {
    var t = a + b;
    a = b;
    b = t;
  }
  return b;
}
```

Comment: Cool analysis, but the OPs question is more about why the function is so much slower in a browser running javascript than in a "native" application running Java than about optimisation of the code.

Comment: Oh, and you can remove `n -= 1;` if you use `while (--n)`

Comment: @RobG Thanks for code suggestion. I just wanted to show that for N big enough (say 1000000), any runtime/language (C++, Java, Javascript) will eventually run equally very slow with OP's algorithm. Because *it is not asymptotically optimal*.

Answer (score 3):

As is fairly well known, the implementation of the fibonacci function you gave in your question requires a lot of steps if implemented naively.  In particular, it takes 7,049,155 calls.

However, these kinds of algorithms can be greatly sped up with a technique known as [memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization).  If you see the function call `fib(32)` taking several seconds, the function is being implemented naively.  If it returns instantly, there is a high probability that the implementation is using memoization.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the evidence already provided the conclusion I draw is:

When the code is not run from the console (like in the jsFiddle where my machine, a Sandy Bridge Macbook Air, computes it in 55ms) the JS engine is able to JIT and possibly automatically memoize the algorithm.

When run from the js console none of this occurs. On my machine it was only under 10x slower: 460ms.

I then edited the code to look for F(38) which bumped the times up to 967ms and 9414ms so it has maintained a similar speedup factor. This indicates that no memoization is being performed and the speedup is probably due to JITting.

Answer (score 1):

Just a comment...

Function calls are relatively expensive, recursion is very expensive and always slower than an equivalent using an efficient loop. e.g the following is thousands of times faster than the recursive alternative in IE:

```
function fib2(n) {
  var arr = [0, 1];
  var len = 2;

  while (len <= n) {
    arr[len] = arr[len-1] + arr[len-2];
    ++len;
  }
  return arr[n];
}
```

And as noted in other answers, it seems the OP algorithm is also inherently slow, but I guess that isn't really the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the memoization approach recommended by @galymzhan, you could also use another algorithm all together. Traditionally, the formula for nth Fibonacci number is F(n) = F(n-1) + F(n-2). This has time complexity that is directly proportional to n.

Dijkstra came up with an algorithm to derive Fibonacci numbers in less than half the steps as specified by the conventional formula. This was outlined in his writing [EDW #654](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/ewd06xx/EWD654.PDF). It goes:

1. For even numbers, F(2n) = (F(n))2 + (F(n+1))2
2. For odd numbers, F(2n+1) = (2F(n) + F(n+1)) * F(n+1) OR F(2n-1) = (2F(n+1) - F(n)) * F(n)